# How can I look for Notifications on Discussions that I have started?

Tags: steam

Earlier, whenever I would ask a question on Steam Forum, I would get a Filter option to just show the discussions that I subscribed to, or to the discussions that I started. I don't find that option anymore in the Notification Bell icon in the Steam app.

Has Steam removed this feature?
If no, please share screenshot on how to filter notifications based on my subscription to discussions/forums.

If yes, what options do I have? Do I need to save the URL? Is that the only option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Steam account data page where the most User data is listed: https://help.steampowered.com/accountdata.

This page assumes you are viewing it under the required Steam account session, and is also available at:

1. Open Steam;
2. Press `"Help" -> "Steam Support"`;
3. Press `"My Account"`;
4. Press `"Data Related to Your Steam Account"`.

---

"Data Related to Your Steam Account" page also lists these pages:

1. [Comments & Discussion Posts](https://steamcommunity.com/my/commenthistory);
2. [Comment Notifications](https://steamcommunity.com/my/commentnotifications);
3. [Discussions Subscription & Usage Data](https://help.steampowered.com/en/accountdata/MyForumMetadata)...

---

On the page `2`, there's tab "Comments on your items":

[image: tab]

---

Ineffably magnificent Steam... ✨